# How can assign multi parameters to the args in spring AOP pointcut

Tags: spring, spring-aop, pointcut

I wrote pointcut like this for the target method aaa. I want to enroll whole parameters of target method to the advice method's parameters. Could you let me know how can I make it.

- target method

```
fun aaa(    
        @RequestParam(value = "startDate")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) startDate: LocalDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "endDate")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) endDate: LocalDate,
        @ModelAttribute privateInfoRequestDTO: PrivateInfoRequestDTO,
        request: HttpServletRequest
    )
```

- advice method's pointcut

```
@Before("@annotation(com.blah.blah...) && args(privateInfoRequestDTO, startDate, endDate, request)")
```

Comment: Feedback, please. It is not particularly polite to ask questions and then ignore answers. You can either accept my answer or comment, if anything is unclear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`JoinPoint.getArgs`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()), if you need a generic solution matching any numbers and types of parameters.

If you know the relative positions from left or right of the parameters you wish to bind using `args(...)`, such as 1st parameter, 2nd-last parameter etc., of course it is more comfortable and type-safe to stick with `args`.

Please also read some documentation before asking questions on StackOverflow next time. Thanks.